# Extract value within brackets using regex

Tags: regex

Below code works fine, and gives the value within brackets (but i want it to return value WITHOUT bracket, output gives me the value but with bracket)

```
  string regularExpressionPattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";

  string inputText = "Find string inside brackets [C#.net] and [Vb.net] example.";

  Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);

  foreach (Match m in re.Matches(inputText))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
  }

  Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Output:

```
[C#.net]
[Vb.net]
[ASP.net]
```

Output Expected:

```
C#.net
Vb.net
ASP.net
```

Comment: What's the use of `regex` for doing this? You can use some other character removing functions. In which language you are working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `m.Value`, use whatever method is used by your undisclosed language to get 1st group, e.g. in C#.NET:

```
m.Groups[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **m.Groups[1].Valu**e to get the desired values in the foreach loop:

```
void Main()
{ 

  string regularExpressionPattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
  string inputText = "Find string inside brackets [C#.net] and [Vb.net] example.";

  Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);

  foreach (Match m in re.Matches(inputText))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
  }
}
```